# When I know the class of an R object, can I call the appropriate method directly?

Tags: r, r-package, r-s3

Consider a simple R function:

```r
#' @importFrom BarPackage Bar
Foo <- function (n, x) {
  replicate(1e6, Bar(numeric(n), x))
}
```

If `Bar()` is a method, then calling `Bar.numeric(numeric(n), x)` saves R from having to look up the class of `numeric(n)`; in a real-world example, this shaves about 10% off my run time.

However, `Bar.numeric()` is a function in a separate package (which I maintain).  Roxygen creates `export(Bar)` and `S3method(Bar, numeric)` entries in NAMESPACE, but if I add `importFrom BarPackage Bar` to the FooPackage NAMESPACE and try to run `Foo()`, I see `Warning message: 'Bar.numeric' is not exported by 'namespace:BarPackage'` -- as indeed it's not.

It feels like I need to create a separate entry in my NAMESPACE reading `export(Bar.numeric)`, but this feels like a very bad idea (in part because I don't think that Roxygen will do it).  Is there any other way of avoiding R having to look up the class of `numeric(n)` on each call to `Bar()`?

Comment: You could call `yourOtherPackage:::Bar.numeric` directly. Not the wisest to use on someone else's package, but if you're the maintainer, not so bad.

Comment: Good suggestion, but sadly not an option here as the packages are destined for CRAN, where this is not permitted.

Comment: Very hacky, but you could rename `Bar.numeric` as, say `Bar_numeric`, and export `Bar_numeric`. Then define `Bar.numeric(Bar, ...) = function(Bar, ...) {Bar_numeric(Bar, ...)}` so the S3 dispatch also works.